Possible to define treeview and menubar independently in Doxygen?
I am using Doxygen version 1.9.8.  I would like to define a menubar that has different entries than the treeview.
I am defining the menu options in a  specified in layout.xml which is included via LAYOUT_FILE in my Doxyfile.  I can create the tabs that I desire to appear in the menubar by modifying navindex, but these changes effect the treeview in the left window pane.
Is there a way to define the menubar and treeview contents separately?  I do not understand their relation.
I have specified a number of tabs with
<tab type="mainpage" visible="yes" title="Some text"></tab>

These tabs create entries in the menubar but do not appear in the treeview.

Did you have a look / experiment with <tab type="user" and <tab type="usergroup" of the layout file, see the https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html
